# Typescript - transform object based on schema

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function `transform` that takes an object of strings, and a validation object, and produces an object of type T, such that each value of the object is transformed to a string, boolean, etc. The following is a minimal example:

```
interface TypeMap {
  boolean: boolean;
  string: string;
}

type Transformers = { [K in keyof TypeMap]: (value: string) => TypeMap[K] }

const transformers: Transformers = {
    string: (value: string) => value,
    boolean: (value: string) => Boolean(value),
};

function transformValue<K extends keyof Transformers>(value: FormDataEntryValue, type: K): TypeMap[K] {
    return transformers[type](String(value)); 
}

function transform<T extends object>(data: Record<string, string>, validation: Record<keyof T, keyof TypeMap>): Partial<T> {
    const entries: [string, FormDataEntryValue][] = Object.entries(data);
    const obj: Partial<T> = {};

    for(const [key, value] of entries) {
        obj[key] = transformValue(value, validation[key]);
    }

    return obj;
}

interface ExampleFormFields {
    lorem: string;
    ipsum: boolean;
}

const formData = { lorem: 'lorem', ipsum: 'true' };

const exampleFormValidation: Record<keyof ExampleFormFields, keyof TypeMap> = { lorem: 'string', ipsum: 'boolean' };

const transformed = transform<ExampleFormFields>(formData, exampleFormValidation);
```

[Here is a TS playground link of the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAUMsgEYD2lANhHCAFwXV0MDcpyAzmFKAHNmvfiAGcAvsWJgsKVFAbcYlKAFto3ZAF4iyANoBpZKGQBrCOkow0cvJgC6zABQA3ODQCuEYX0EBKHQA+W2x7IwdkKWIEShBeZD4lFXVNZgVk1Q0oLV0SMjIRQRd3Lx8ePzFA7RDS7wAaLjIqWnomZDcPb19RAWqQgCFWNs6y-0aJTmIYTxAEMGA4xMV4lLUANS6IAB5jCAAPSBAAEy0LKxsM1azNINHu5AAxLIARODA4AFFwKHRNsvqiTkzEM-nSdnwESITWQUAgYE8UBAy0yqRy+lk2AczgAypUBPcIP5-OxkMRojM5gslklruptqhkAcjqdkJRyAArCDzO7Hd5wZgAJW5qmO2yKYkBEoEQUBpWAfOp7WFsSgYvO1jQgI1lwhmCCYOQAAU4FAFh4GSF8gVYvEwEyfsAINxmPppYDnuo3h9vnw-lsHPpIroAPKc7lgAB0EEdzucirgJJhtoS7I5zBNZuAFtQITyk2kBWQKWcKft+nOcoDbJsMb8zsC1qLZDTFcswZRdI2W0JVZoCveixAbfQDiTReiRbhCKRbM5kmkoEgsEQKE++zgakwdE9akeTporKbyBoqggah6gk4ReAmG4ngvLFaHHJ0jLxde-J0elPcMfAHJf3Pf9AVve8AL4bx-yiKZ3wOTdtwgXd-gHJUhRFNVth1ZB1wQncsn3CBD24bVLE1DAwnwPMfzPADpRAkw7wfZh-xaNgQGggsYjiBJaWUG5jm-Pi1m2XCt3w9RCOIu41m9OBAXg8SkKyFDFSHEkgA)

The errors I'm getting are related to the line `obj[key] = transformValue(value, validation[key]);`, and I can't work out where things are going wrong.

Comment: Apologies, in creating a minimal example I introduced a typo. Code and link are fixed now.

Comment: I would approach it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/Wkz5Dm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?